# Entering 2 numbers upon user input, separated by spacing

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to write a program in Python that multiplies two 2x2 matrices. I'm having trouble with the user input where the user is required to enter 2 digits which represents one row of the matrix.

```
userin = int(input("Enter first 2x2 matrix: ")).split(' ')

print(userin)
```

I'm getting an error saying:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 4'

What I'm trying to get is something like:

```
Enter first 2x2 matrix: 3 4
Enter second 2x2 matrix: 7 9
Here's your matrix: [[3,4],[7,9]]     #this is for testing purpose
```

I'm having problem with the user input where I want to first input the first digit such as 3, then hitting the spacebar to enter the second digit which is 4. Wouldn't adding the `split(' ')` be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to int after the split using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
userin = [int(x) for x in input("Enter first 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
import numpy as np

row1 = list(map(int, input("Enter first 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')))
row2 = list(map(int, input("Enter second 2x2 matrix: ").split(' ')))

arr = np.vstack((row1, row2))
```